# Wizard's Battleshaping: Extending duration & Considered magic?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

*Wizards School (transmutation), sub-school (**Shapechanging**), from the Advanced Player's Guide.*

You are granted a power replacement for *Telekinetic Fist* called **Battleshaping**,  which allows you to grow some natural weapons for a short time. It states that this ability grants you a +1 (or greater) enhancement bonus to your claws. Does simply having a generic enhancement bonus allow it to be considered a magical weapon?

Follow-up question:
Is there any known way to increase its duration past 1 round without having to spend a swift action each turn?

Comment: The second question should be in a question of it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes, it does.

The rules for [Damage Reduction](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Overcoming-DR) state:

> Damage Reduction may be overcome by special materials, **magic weapons (*any weapon with a +1 or higher enhancement bonus, not counting the enhancement from masterwork quality*)**, certain types of weapons (such as slashing or bludgeoning), and weapons imbued with an alignment.

Therefore, having an enhancement bonus would make it count as a magic weapon.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, they are

Just like when using the [Magic Fang](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-fang/) or [Magic Weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon/) spells, the targets are considered *magic* weapons because the source of those [enhancement bonuses](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Enhancement-Bonus) is also a magical source, [Battleshaping](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/transmutation/shapechange/), a [supernatural](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-) ability.

As far as I know, there isn't a single source of enhancement bonus that isn't a spell, spell-like, or supernatural ability, other than the bonus from masterwork quality. For clarification, this is how [Magic Weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/) are defined:

> A magic weapon is enhanced to strike more truly and deliver more damage. Magic weapons have enhancement bonuses ranging from +1 to +5. They apply these bonuses to both attack and damage rolls when used in combat. All magic weapons are also masterwork weapons, but their masterwork bonuses on attack rolls do not stack with their enhancement bonuses on attack rolls.

As for extending the duration, there is none. If it was a spell-like ability, instead, you could use the [Extend Spell-like Ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/frog-god-games/monster-feats-3pp-frog-god-games/extend-spell-like-ability/) monster feat.